# Not able to access related objects fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm new to rails and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Everything I've read says that I'm doing this right.

I have a relationships between two models.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :votes
     belongs_to :user
  end
```

And

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :votes
  has_many :photos
end
```

Here are my Controller methods

```
def index 
  @photos = Photo.order("created_at desc").to_a 
end



def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.user_id = current_user.id
    if !@photo.save
      @error = @photo.errors.full_messages.join('. ')
      render view_for_new
      return
    end
  end
```

I know the relationship works because in my view when I do this: `<%= photo.user %>` I get a user object back, and when I do `<%= photo.user.inspect %>` it shows all the expected fields with the correct keys and values.

However I want to access fields such as username, email, etc and display those on the page. How do I do this? I've tried doing `<%= photo.user.email %>` and some other fields that are available but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: `<%= photo.user.email %>` generates an error ?

Comment: yes, `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` which doesn't really make sense to me since it's a key.

Comment: @Baldrick the only thing I can think of is that I messed up the migrations but I'm not really sure how to check to see what's wrong.

Comment: It means there is no user for the photo (ie `photo.user` is `nil`). Check how the photo has been initialized, and check there's a value in DB for `photos#user_id`. Add the code of the controller where `photo` is initialized if you need more help.

Comment: `def index
    @photos = Photo.order("created_at desc").to_a
  end` 

This is what I have in my controller, when I do `<%= photo.user %>` thought it doesn't return nill, there's an actual object on the page, or what I believe to be an object.

In the DB the photo in question also has a user_id value.

Comment: Sorry I have no clue...

Comment: @Baldrick Alright, thanks, hopefully someone will come by that might know. It gets even weirder. When I do <%= photo.user.inspect %> It prints out the entire object and all it's fields, and everything is correct. No idea why it can't grab them by their key...

Comment: Where are you trying to access photo.user (e.g. what view contains the code `<%= photo.user.email %`)? How are you instantiating the photo object for that code snippet? (i.e. post your controller code) When you look at the row for the photo in question via workbench or console or whatever, what user_id are you seeing? Does it correspond with an actual row in the user table?

Comment: I'm trying to access it in my index view. I posted the controller code in one of the comments here. It's just a basic index in the controller. When I look at the row for the photo I see user_id : 1, which is what I expect. It corresponds with an actual user. When I do `<%= photo.user.inspect %>` instead, it shows the entire object printed out in a human readable format.  `#<User id: 1, email: "example@example.com", username: "example">` That is just a snippet of it. @MarsAtomic

Comment: In your index action, why are you appending a .to_a here => "def index @photos = Photo.order("created_at desc").to_a end"? This turns your object collection into any array which I don't think is what you want to do for a basic index action.

Comment: Please don't ever post code into comments. It's difficult to read. Instead, edit your original post to include the requested information. If you'd done so, you might already have the answer to this question. You also didn't post the *full* code. You have an ActiveRecordRelationship containing Photo objects, but I don't see anyplace where you actually instantiated the `photo` field you're trying to use. Maybe you've done it correctly someplace, but I can't tell because you didn't post the full code.

Comment: @ValAsensio I didn't think it made a difference since in my view I'm looping over all entries anyways. I got rid of it and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Alright question is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright figured this out, or at least partially.

Instead of `<%= photo.user.email %>` I did `<%= photo.user.try(:email) %>` and that brought the correct attribute back that I was looking for. It seems the association is done correctly. I don't know why `<%= photo.user.email %>` doesn't work, everywhere I look on line seems to use that sort of syntax.